# Reading from stdin into a FILE*

Tags: c, file, io, stdin

I have a functions that expects a FILE* and I usually create that by reading from a file. Now under certain circumstances I want to read from stdin. Is there a way to read a sentence with previously unspecified length from stdin and write it into a FILE* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are already of type `FILE *`. So you can use it like any other `FILE *` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use `fp` and `stdin` as needed

```
void copyline(FILE *fp) {
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(stdin) != EOF) && (ch != '\n')) {
        fputc(ch, fp);
    }
    if (ch != EOF) fputc('\n', fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getchar()` on a line buffered terminal and read it like this:

```
 int i;
 while((i=getchar())!=EOF)
```

And then use it to write it into a file.